# ugarchfit diagnostic tests: goodness of fit

Tags: goodness-of-fit, garch

I modeled a couple of financial return time series with different kinds of GARCH-models and different distribution termns and now whant to compare them. I very often face the problem that all diagnostic tests show great results but Adjusted Pearson Goodness-of-Fit Test is rejected. 
I am not sure about this test: is this a reason not to use the model although it provides good forecasting results? 
Important is that the model is good in forecasting the values!
The same is sometimes the case Sign Bias test.

Thank you!